# Calling model.fit multiple time over different dataset when training TensorFlow model

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, reinforcement-learning

I have been working on a AlphaGo Zero clone using TensorFlow and Keras. It seems to work fine, but I am not sure if the code I use to train my model make sense:

```python
    def train_from_game_log(self, game_log):
        half_point = len(game_log['x'])//2
        x = np.array(game_log['x'][half_point:])
        y0 = np.array(game_log['y'][0][half_point:])
        y1 = np.array(game_log['y'][1][half_point:])
        self.model.fit(x, [y0, y1], shuffle=True, batch_size=64, epochs=4)

        x = tf.image.rot90(x, k=1)
        y0 = np.reshape(y0, (-1,self.input_board_size, self.input_board_size, 1))
        y0 = tf.image.rot90(y0, k=1)
        y0 = np.reshape(y0, (-1,self.input_board_size*self.input_board_size))
        self.model.fit(x, [y0, y1], shuffle=True, batch_size=64, epochs=4)

        x = tf.image.rot90(x, k=1)
        y0 = np.reshape(y0, (-1,self.input_board_size, self.input_board_size, 1))
        y0 = tf.image.rot90(y0, k=1)
        y0 = np.reshape(y0, (-1,self.input_board_size*self.input_board_size))
        self.model.fit(x, [y0, y1], shuffle=True, batch_size=64, epochs=4)
        
        x = tf.image.rot90(x, k=1)
        y0 = np.reshape(y0, (-1,self.input_board_size, self.input_board_size, 1))
        y0 = tf.image.rot90(y0, k=1)
        y0 = np.reshape(y0, (-1,self.input_board_size*self.input_board_size))
        self.model.fit(x, [y0, y1], shuffle=True, batch_size=64, epochs=4)
```

I am rotating my dataset and run `fit()` again on the model.

Does it make sense to train it like this?
Would this bias the model to the last rotation?
Should I make a generator instead?

Comment: You should use [`tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator)

Comment: Thanks, I just see the `seed` option in the example for applying same random transformation to `x` and `y0`

Comment: another problem is I have a scalar and an image in y, makes it tricky to make a generator